# Detection of hotkey using Keyboard.GetKeyStates with non-elevated app when elevated app has focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a program which allows users to create hotkeys to show and hide it. I do this by calling `System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.GetKeyStates` to check if hotkeys have been pressed. My app has to run as non-elevated. The problem I'm having is, when other programs that are elevated have focus, `GetKeyStates` only returns true for specific keys (*ctrl, shift, alt, esc*) but not other keys. Is this expected behavior? I can't find any documentation detailing it.

When I run my app elevated, it does return true correctly for every key. However, I can't run my app elevated, so it's an issue.

Here's some sample code I tested:

```
    'TRUE when elevated and non-elevated apps have focus
    isKeyPressed(Key.LeftCtrl)
    isKeyPressed(Key.LeftShift)
    isKeyPressed(Key.LeftAlt)
    isKeyPressed(Key.Escape)

    'TRUE only when non-elevated apps have focus
    isKeyPressed(Key.OemPeriod)
    isKeyPressed(Key.F12)
    isKeyPressed(Key.A)

Public Function isKeyPressed(ByRef keys As System.Windows.Input.Key)
    If (Windows.Input.Keyboard.GetKeyStates(keys) And Windows.Input.KeyStates.Down) > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: To me, that sounds like a security feature.  You don't want non-elevated processes to be able to monitor keystrokes from elevated processes.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's strange that it allows some keystrokes to be detected.